# C - Oscillator configuration on dsPIC33e

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am trying to configure the oscillator of a dsPIC33e to reach 40 MIPS but the cycle frequency reached is half what I want.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <p33EP32GS504.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h> // Allow assembly code

/** OSCILLATOR CONFIGURATION **************/
// Select Internal FRC at POR
_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRC & IESO_OFF);
// Enable Clock Switching and Configure Primary Oscillator in XT mode
_FOSC(FCKSM_CSECMD & OSCIOFNC_OFF & POSCMD_NONE);

void initOsc(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   initOsc(); // configure Osc
   TRISA =  0b00111; // Set PORTA I/O

   while(1) 
   { 
      asm("btg LATA, #3");
      asm("btg LATA, #3");
   }
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void initOsc(void)
{
   PLLFBD = 63; // M=65
   CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=1; // N1=3
   CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; // N2=2

   // Initiate Clock Switch to FRC oscillator with PLL (NOSC=0b001)
   __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);
   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);
   // Wait for Clock switch to occur
   while (OSCCONbits.COSC!= 0b001);
   // Wait for PLL to lock
   while (OSCCONbits.LOCK!= 1);
}
```

In the configuration `function initOsc()`, the datasheet gives `Fout = Fin*M/(N1*N2)`, which gives in my case, `Fout = 80 MHz` and `Fcycle = Fout/2 = 40MHz`

In the main function, after calling the configuration function, I make a LED blink. Then, I observe the output on pin 3 of PORTA with an oscilloscope. The time between the toggle of the pin is 50ns (20MHz) and the OSCOUT pin shows a fosc of 25ns (40MHz).

I have a factor 2 between the real values and what I want.

What do I miss? Where is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Your Fin should be about 7,6 MHz, right? Did you check that also?

Comment: I found out that the measure by the oscilloscope was not done correctly. After setting it up in a proper way, my new time between the toggle is 50ns (20MHz) and the OSC pin out shows 25ns (40MHz).

I still have a Fcycle 2x smaller than what I want. (I edited the initial question with these values)

Comment: I tried to measure the Fin by commenting the line `initiOsc()` and I now have a 3.6MHz clock on OSC pin out...it should be 7.6MHz right?